# How to deserialize a Memory Mapped File View into an object?

Tags: c#, file, memory, reflection

I'm looking for a way to parse a memory mapped file view and save its contents in an object. Basically what I'm trying to do is read a binary and save it in an object. In C++ I would simply create a file mapping with *CreateFileMapping* and map a file view with *MapViewOfFile* and then dump the view in a struct (eg. **IMAGE_DOS_HEADER**). Is there any way to do this in C#?

```
        try
        {
            using (MemoryMappedFile mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(path, FileMode.Open))
            {
                _mva = mmf.CreateViewAccessor(0, PeOffset.DosHeader);
                _mva.Read<MyType>(myTypeInstance);
                action?.Invoke(imageHeaders);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error opening file");
            _logger.Error(ex);
        }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is smelly that `_mva` is a field, make it a local variable instead, within a `using` construct too (it should be disposed). Apart from that, `Read` should work, provided that your `MyType` struct has all the marshaling attributes configured correctly.

Comment: Thanks! _mva is a static field and is used by a few methods. Looks like I'll have to look into marshaling attributes then :)

Comment: that's most certainly a bad idea, since the view is invalid right after you dispose `mmf`, and accessing the view it from multiple threads would be disastrous.

Comment: You're right, I didn't catch it. Thanks again!

Comment: Note that [`UnmanagedMemoryAccessor.Read()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd294202(v=vs.110).aspx) doesn't really deserialize the object in the normal sense of the term. Ideally it will pin/memcpy/unpin to transfer the data.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using SafeMemoryMappedViewHandle inside an unsafe block to write the data